# java phone number validation

Tags: java, regex, validation

Here is my problem:

Create a constructor for a telephone number given a string in the form xxx-xxx-xxxx or xxx-xxxx for a local number. Throw an exception if the format is not valid.

So I was thinking to validate it using a regular expression, but I don't know if I'm doing it correctly. Also what kind of exception would I have to throw? Do I need to create my own exception?

```
    public TelephoneNumber(String aString){
        if(isPhoneNumberValid(aString)==true){
            StringTokenizer tokens = new StringTokenizer("-");
            if(tokens.countTokens()==3){
                areaCode = Integer.parseInt(tokens.nextToken());
                exchangeCode = Integer.parseInt(tokens.nextToken());
                number = Integer.parseInt(tokens.nextToken());
            }
            else if(tokens.countTokens()==2){
                exchangeCode = Integer.parseInt(tokens.nextToken());
                number = Integer.parseInt(tokens.nextToken());
            }
            else{
                //throw an excemption here
            }
        }

    }


 public static boolean isPhoneNumberValid(String phoneNumber){
     boolean isValid = false;

     //Initialize reg ex for phone number.
    String expression = "(\\d{3})(\\[-])(\\d{4})$";
    CharSequence inputStr = phoneNumber;
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(expression);
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(inputStr);
    if(matcher.matches()){
        isValid = true;
     }
        return isValid;
    }
```

Hi sorry, yes this is homework. For this assignments the only valid format are xxx-xxx-xxxx and xxx-xxxx, all other formats (xxx)xxx-xxxx or xxxxxxxxxx are invalid in this case.

I would like to know if my regular expression is correct

Comment: is this homework? should be tagged as such if so...

Comment: Obvious question: Are you sure that your phone number format catches any variety of phone number that your users might want to enter? Nothing is more frustrating than a half-smart system that refuses to accept perfectly valid data. (Oh, and if this is only homework - never mind.)

Comment: Completely agree with @Tomalak. If this is a production system, the correct answer is to strip out any non-numeric characters and validate the resulting number.

Comment: StringTokenizer is BAD practice.

Comment: "StringTokenizer is BAD practice."  @fuzzy lollipop, it would be helpful to provide an explanation why this is bad practice, as in @haldean's answer below.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> *So I was thinking to validate it using a regular expression, but I don't know if I'm doing it correctly.*

It indeed looks overcomplicated. Also, matching `xxx-xxx-xxxx` or `xxx-xxxx` where `x` is a digit can be done better with `"(\\d{3}-){1,2}\\d{4}"`. To learn more about regex I recommend to go through http://regular-expressions.info.

> *Also what kind of exception would I have to throw? Do I need to create my own exception?*

A `ValidatorException` seems straight forward.

```
public static void isPhoneNumberValid(String phoneNumber) throws ValidatorException {
    if (!phoneNumber.matches(regex)) {
        throws ValidatorException("Invalid phone number");
    }
}
```

If you don't want to create one yourself for some reasons, then I'd probably pick `IllegalArgumentException`, but still, I don't recommend that.

That said, this validation of course doesn't cover international and/or external telephone numbers. Unless this is really homework, I'd suggest to rethink the validation.

Answer (score 4):

```
^(([(]?(\d{2,4})[)]?)|(\d{2,4})|([+1-9]+\d{1,2}))?[-\s]?(\d{2,3})?[-\s]?((\d{7,8})|(\d{3,4}[-\s]\d{3,4}))$
```

matches:
(0060)123-12345678, (0060)12312345678, (832)123-1234567, (006)03-12345678,

(006)03-12345678, 00603-12345678, 0060312345678

0000-123-12345678, 0000-12-12345678, 0000-1212345678 ... etc.

1234-5678, 01-123-4567

Can replace '-' with SPACE i.e (0080) 123 12345678

Also matches +82-123-1234567, +82 123 1234567, +800 01 12345678 ... etc.

More for house-hold/private number. 
Not for 1-800-000-0000 type of number

[*Tested with Regex tester http://regexpal.com/](http://regexpal.com/)

Comment: Please read the question instead of only the title. This is not exactly what the OP is asking. *"For this assignments the only valid format are xxx-xxx-xxxx and xxx-xxxx, all other formats (xxx)xxx-xxxx or xxxxxxxxxx are invalid in this case."*

Comment: As this is the second time you're doing, I just want to inform that Stack Overflow is a Question & Answer site. It is not a discussion forum where everyone looking for the exact answer has to wade through a mess of repeated/overgeneralized answers in order to find the exact answer one is looking for.

Comment: FYI, a lot of developers are looking for 'similar' but not exact answers. I'm just trying to contribute back to the community so they don have to wade through other webs to look for what they want. Like my case, I just want to have a comprehensive validation regex & this page inspired me. Despite not directly answered, my post at least fit to the context. It's hard to look for someone who ask the same question U wish.

Answer (score 0):

You could match those patterns pretty easily as suggested by BalusC.

As a side note, `StringTokenizer` has been deprecated. From [JavaDoc](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/StringTokenizer.html):

> StringTokenizer is a legacy class that is retained for compatibility reasons although its use is discouraged in new code. It is recommended that anyone seeking this functionality use the split method of String or the java.util.regex package instead.

An easier way to split your string into the appropriate segments would be:

```
String phoneParts[] = phoneNumber.split("-");
```

Answer (score -3):

String pincode = "589877";

```
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\d{6}");
```

\d indicates the digits. inside the braces the number of digits
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(pincode);

```
    if (matcher.matches()) {
        System.out.println("Pincode is Valid");
        return true;
    } else {
        System.out.println("pincode must be a 6 digit Number");
```