# Patterns for phone number prefixes - validation

Tags: java

I have looked up patterns for the following: 1300, 1-300-, 1800, 1-800- followed by 10 digits and 13, 1-3- followed by 6 digits.  They all look pretty long winded, was wondering if any one had any solutions using regular expressions only

Comment: [libphonenumber](https://code.google.com/p/libphonenumber/), [and these](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9412320/1079354) [two SO questions](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2555182/1079354)...

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [libphonenumber](https://code.google.com/p/libphonenumber/) and let it take care of validation, formatting etc. Form their website

> What is it?
>
> Google's common Java, C++ and Javascript library for parsing,
>   formatting, storing and validating international phone numbers. The
>   Java version is optimized for running on smartphones, and is used by
>   the Android framework since 4.0 (Ice Cream Sandwich).

Comment: Thanks Pangea, but iam not sure i would be allowed to use this as it beyond the level we are at at the moment.  I think we have to use regular expressons